# Unable to apply multiple filters in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to apply filters on multiple brands of guitars in my Guitar Products Screen. However, I'm able to apply filter for only one brand, and when I click on the label for the next brand or want to unselect the existing brand's label, the app freezes with an **Invalid Array Length** error.

**My Code**:

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';

import '../global_variables/global_variables.dart';
import '../widgets/animated_bottom_bar.dart';
import '../widgets/custom_appbar.dart';
import '../widgets/instrument_card.dart';
import 'instrument_detail.dart';

class ElectricGuitarsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ElectricGuitarsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ElectricGuitarsScreen> createState() => _ElectricGuitarsScreenState();
}

List<Map<String, dynamic>> guitarList = [];
List<Map<String, dynamic>> filteredGuitars = [];
List<Map<String, dynamic>> filteredGuitarsByBrands = [];
List<String> guitarBrandList = [];
List<String> selectedBrands = [];

void populateGuitarList() {
  guitarList.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < instruments.length; i++) {
    if (instruments[i]["instrument"].toString().toLowerCase() == "guitar") {
      guitarList.add(instruments[i]);
    }
  }
}

void populateGuitarBrandList() {
  guitarBrandList.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
    guitarBrandList.add(guitarList[i]["brand"]);
  }
  guitarBrandList = guitarBrandList.toSet().toList();
}

double minGuitarPrice = 10000000;
double maxGuitarPrice = -1;

void findMinPrice() {
  for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
    if (guitarList[i]["price"] < minGuitarPrice) {
      minGuitarPrice = guitarList[i]["price"];
    }
  }
}

void findMaxPrice() {
  for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
    if (guitarList[i]["price"] > maxGuitarPrice) {
      maxGuitarPrice = guitarList[i]["price"];
    }
  }
}

double minSearchPrice = minGuitarPrice;
double maxSearchPrice = maxGuitarPrice;

class _ElectricGuitarsScreenState extends State<ElectricGuitarsScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _searchBoxController = TextEditingController();
  final String _hintText = "Search instruments...";
  int _currentIndex = 1;
  int count = 0;

  RangeValues rv = RangeValues(0, 1000000);

  void changeSearchPrice(double minsp, maxsp) {
    setState(() {
      minSearchPrice = minsp;
      maxSearchPrice = maxsp;
      populateGuitarList();
      count++;
    });
  }

  void populateFilteredGuitars(double minp, double maxp) {
    filteredGuitars.clear();
    filteredGuitarsByBrands.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
      if (guitarList[i]["price"] <= maxp && guitarList[i]["price"] >= minp) {
        filteredGuitars.add(guitarList[i]);
      }
    }
    if (selectedBrands.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < filteredGuitars.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < selectedBrands.length; j++) {
          if (filteredGuitars[i]["brand"] == selectedBrands[j]) {
            filteredGuitarsByBrands.add(filteredGuitars[i]);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      filteredGuitars = filteredGuitarsByBrands;
    }
  }

  bool isBrandSelected = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    populateGuitarList();
    findMinPrice();
    findMaxPrice();
    minSearchPrice = minGuitarPrice;
    maxSearchPrice = maxGuitarPrice;
    rv = RangeValues(minSearchPrice, maxSearchPrice);
    populateFilteredGuitars(minSearchPrice, maxSearchPrice);
    populateGuitarBrandList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double? screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double? screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          CustomAppBar(
            screenWidth: screenWidth,
            screenHeight: screenHeight,
            searchBoxController: _searchBoxController,
            hintText: _hintText,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: screenWidth * 0.025),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.sort_rounded,
                    size: screenWidth * 0.05,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.02)),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                "₹ $minGuitarPrice",
                style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(
                  color: primaryColor,
                  fontSize: screenWidth * 0.025,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: screenWidth * 0.7,
                child: RangeSlider(
                  min: minGuitarPrice,
                  max: maxGuitarPrice,
                  divisions: 100,
                  values: rv,
                  labels: RangeLabels(
                      rv.start.round().toString(), rv.end.round().toString()),
                  activeColor: primaryColor,
                  inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
                  onChanged: (values) {
                    setState(() {
                      rv = values;
                      populateFilteredGuitars(rv.start, rv.end);
                      count++;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "₹ $maxGuitarPrice",
                style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(
                  color: primaryColor,
                  fontSize: screenWidth * 0.025,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.02)),
          SizedBox(
            height: screenHeight * 0.025,
            width: screenWidth * 0.9,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: guitarBrandList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                if (!selectedBrands
                                    .contains(guitarBrandList[index])) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedBrands.add(guitarBrandList[index]);
                                    populateFilteredGuitars(rv.start, rv.end);
                                    count++;
                                  });
                                } else {
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedBrands
                                        .remove(guitarBrandList[index]);
                                    populateFilteredGuitars(rv.start, rv.end);
                                    count++;
                                  });
                                }
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: screenWidth * 0.2,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: (!selectedBrands
                                          .contains(guitarBrandList[index]))
                                      ? Colors.grey.shade200
                                      : primaryColor,
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(10)),
                                ),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    guitarBrandList[index],
                                    style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(
                                      color: (!selectedBrands
                                              .contains(guitarBrandList[index]))
                                          ? primaryColor
                                          : tertiaryColor,
                                      fontSize: screenWidth * 0.02,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.02)),
          SizedBox(
            width: screenWidth,
            height: screenHeight * 0.8,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: screenWidth * 0.025),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: AnimationLimiter(
                      key: ValueKey("list $count"),
                      child: GridView.count(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: screenWidth * 0.01,
                        mainAxisSpacing: screenWidth * 0.01,
                        childAspectRatio: 0.75,
                        children:
                            List.generate(filteredGuitars.length, (index) {
                          return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredGrid(
                            position: index,
                            columnCount: 2,
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
                            child: SlideAnimation(
                              child: FadeInAnimation(
                                child: InstrumentCard(
                                    width: (screenWidth * 0.47),
                                    height: (screenWidth * 0.47) / 0.75,
                                    instrumentImageUrl: filteredGuitars[index]
                                        ["img-url"],
                                    instrumentName: filteredGuitars[index]
                                        ["name"],
                                    instrumentMrp:
                                        "₹${filteredGuitars[index]["mrp"].toString()}",
                                    instrumentPrice:
                                        "₹${filteredGuitars[index]["price"].toString()}",
                                    paddingRight: 0,
                                    innerHorizontalSymmetricPadding: 10,
                                    innerVerticalSymmetricPadding: 0,
                                    instrumentDiscount:
                                        "${(((1 - (filteredGuitars[index]["price"] / filteredGuitars[index]["mrp"])) * 100).round()).toString()}% off",
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  InstrumentDetail(
                                                      instrument:
                                                          filteredGuitars[
                                                              index])));
                                    },
                                    onWishTap: () {
                                      if (wishList
                                          .contains(filteredGuitars[index])) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          wishList
                                              .remove(filteredGuitars[index]);
                                          //count++;
                                        });
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          wishList.add(filteredGuitars[index]);
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                    onCartTap: () {
                                      if (cartList.contains(
                                              filteredGuitars[index]) ==
                                          false) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          cartList.add(filteredGuitars[index]);
                                          cartMap.addAll(
                                              {filteredGuitars[index]: 1});
                                        });
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          cartList
                                              .remove(filteredGuitars[index]);
                                          cartMap
                                              .remove(filteredGuitars[index]);
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                    isWishlisted: (wishList
                                            .contains(filteredGuitars[index]))
                                        ? true
                                        : false,
                                    isCarted: (cartList
                                            .contains(filteredGuitars[index]))
                                        ? true
                                        : false,
                                    instrument: filteredGuitars[index]),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: screenHeight * 0.025)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: screenWidth * 0.025, vertical: screenHeight * 0.015),
        child: CustomAnimatedBottomBar(
          containerHeight: 56,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
          showElevation: true,
          itemCornerRadius: 10,
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
          items: navBarItems,
          onItemSelected: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What is causing the error in my app and how to rectify it?

Comment: Try the [flutter_list](https://pub.dev/packages/filter_list) package it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. I needed to filter for the brand lists before applying the price filter.

**Updated Code**:

```
void populateFilteredGuitars(double minp, double maxp) {
    filteredGuitars.clear();

    filteredGuitarsByBrands.clear();
    //filteredGuitarsByPrice.clear();

    if (selectedBrands.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < selectedBrands.length; j++) {
          if (guitarList[i]["brand"] == selectedBrands[j]) {
            filteredGuitarsByBrands.add(guitarList[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (selectedBrands.isEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < guitarList.length; i++) {
        if (guitarList[i]["price"] <= maxp && guitarList[i]["price"] >= minp) {
          filteredGuitars.add(guitarList[i]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      filteredGuitars.clear();
      for (int i = 0; i < filteredGuitarsByBrands.length; i++) {
        if (filteredGuitarsByBrands[i]["price"] <= maxp &&
            filteredGuitarsByBrands[i]["price"] >= minp) {
          filteredGuitars.add(filteredGuitarsByBrands[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```